# Printing to a bluetooth printer using iPhone

Tags: cocoa, ios, bluetooth, touch, printing

I wasn't able to find a clean answer on this, is there or is there not a way to connect my iPhone to a bluetooth printer to execute some printing tasks?
I'm developing the app myself, so what framework could possibly do this? i read that Apple's External Accessory Framework handles bluetooth communication, but is it possible to print using that framework?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a direct answer, but: printing support is an announced feature of iOS 4.2, due in November.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question is 2 years old, things change and this was the first result for what I was looking for I decided to submit this answer after some "research".

From the SAME Apple Technical Q&A

> Note: Bluetooth low energy accessories do not interface with the
>   External Accessory framework and **are not required to be MFi compliant**.
>   Instead, apps use the [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html) framework to communicate with
>   Bluetooth low energy accessories from iOS or OS X.

So, it may have not been possible 2 years ago, but it is possible now.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** As the accepted answer points out, things are different since I posted this answer in 2010. The answer is left for posterity.

From an [Apple Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1657/_index.html):

> The External Accessory framework is designed to allow iPhone OS applications to communicate only with hardware accessories that are developed under Apple's Made For iPod (MFi) and Works With iPhone licensee program. MFi compliant accessories can be implemented as wired devices, meaning they plug in to the iPhone or iPod touch's 30-pin connector, or as wireless devices, whereby they use Bluetooth as the communication channel. Either way, an application that uses the External Accessory framework will not be notified of an accessory's presence unless the accessory identifies itself as being MFi compliant, i.e., it was specifically designed to interface with an iPhone OS application.
>
> More information about developing MFi accessories can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/sdk/accessories.html).